# Use test name rather than method name for extent reporter

Tags: java, testng, appium-android, extentreports

I want to use the test name I'm giving the report rather than the method name.

This is where I am naming the test.

```
@Test(testName = "The test name is test", retryAnalyzer = RetryAnalyzer.class)
```

This is the before method where I am getting the test name

```
 @BeforeMethod
public synchronized void beforeMethod(Method method) {
    ExtentTest child = parentTest.get().createNode(method.getName());
    test.set(child);
```

I would like the before method to read the test name at the start of the test.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of @Test(testName = “ The test name is the test”) 
Use  @Test(Description = “ The test name is the test”)

And 
Use this below line.

ExtentTest child = parenttest.get().createNode(method.getDescription().getName());

This works!!

Comment: I get "cannot resolve symbol" on the .getDescription().

Comment: If your using testng library to define ur tests (@Test) then it should get resolved.

Comment: I am using testNG to define, version 6.8?

Comment: Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the TestListener, i am changing the name of the test method with the parameters which has data fetched from csv at run time

```
public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
//      System.out.println(("*** Running Test method " + result.getMethod().getMethodName() + "..."));
//      ExtentTestManager.startTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName());
        System.out.println(("*** Running Test method " + result.getMethod().getMethodName() + "..."));
        String methodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
        Object[] parameters = result.getParameters();
        if(result.getMethod().getMethodName().equalsIgnoreCase("DbEnvSet")||result.getMethod().getMethodName().equalsIgnoreCase("closeDbConnections")){
        }else{
            if (parameters != null && parameters.length > 0) {
                methodName = "Method : " + parameters[0].toString() ;
                ExtentTestManager.startTest(methodName);
            }

        }
        this.testStatus =   new TestStatus();
    }
```

I am using Dataprovider and reading the data from a csv file

```
  @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "DbEnvSet" }, dataProvider = "ReadRecords", dataProviderClass = RecordsDataProvider.class)
    @Parameters({"environment","dbUserName","dbPassword"})
    //,String TransactionTime,String SessionID,String TypeOfScenario,String Amount
    public void End2EndScenario(String Number,String scenario,String error) throws Exception {
}
```

Here Number,scenario and error are the values which are being read from csv [image]